# AWS - Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I got an error: **Cannot read property 'username' of undefined** and also the const username will say that it is not used.

Complete Errror:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:7:50)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    console.log(event);
    const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
    const username = event.queryStringParameters.username;
    addConnectionId(connectionId).then(() => {    
        callback(null, {        
            statusCode: 200,       
            });
    });};

function addConnectionId(connectionId) {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'Chat',
        Item: {
            'connection_id' : connectionId,
            'username' : username
        }
    };
    return ddb.put(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: Adding a print to output the contents of event might help :)

Comment: Hello. I did the console.log(event) but the output is `{requestContext: { connectionId: 'Connection01', username: 'string' }}` :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `Use Lambda Proxy integration` to access query parameters.

Comment: Hello. I already did. May trigger is the $connect in my API Gateway

Comment: @RookieDev  Please double check if you have correctly set up lambda proxy integration. It should work.

Comment: I already enabled the Lambda Proxy integration but still get this error.